# Command to Shutdown SQL Server via the CLI

Tags: sql-server, shell, command-line

I'm creating a custom docker image and which to shutdown SQL Server as one of the steps.

I can't seem to find the a CLI command to do this? There's heaps of docs about starting SQL Server via the CLI. Just not stopping/shutting down.

Is this possible?

Also, prefer bash/linux based answers as I'm doing this against a linux version of SQL Server 2017 (image used: `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu`)

Comment: did you check this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/shutdown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Nope @Yeou - I totally forgot about executing SQL from the CLI to achieve this. Post that as an answer and you'll get the credit. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/shutdown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) from Microsoft on how to shutdown sql server.

e.g.

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -E -S localhost -Q "SHUTDOWN"
```